# Proving $\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}{m}^2 \binom{m}{n-k}=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How can I prove this?
$$\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}{m}^2 \binom{m}{n-k}=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}$$

$$ 0\le k \le n $$
I developed the expressions, but they are not the same. I do not know if it will be my mistake or the advisor
I tried to solve for the binomial, but I could not, any idea to be able to proceed

Comment: I think that they are the same. Try with small numbers to check

Comment: How can I prove it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some binomial coefficient identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424724/some-binomial-coefficient-identity)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the general identity $$\sum_{k\ge0}\binom ak\binom bk\binom kc=\binom ac\binom{a+b-c}a$$ Inserting $n$ for $a$ and $b$ and $n-k$ for $c$ yields what you wanted to prove.
The upper bound of summation can be reduced from $\infty$ to $n$ because $\binom nk$ is 0 for $k\gt n$.

EDIT: This can be proven using Vandermonde's identity. @user gives a very simple proof in their answer.

Comment: It would be nice to give a proof of the general identity or at least a reference to it.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{n}{m}^{2}\binom{m}{n-k}=\binom{n}{k}\sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{n}{m}\binom{k}{n-m}=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{n}$$where the second equality rests on the [vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Comment: 1. How did you extract the $\color{limegreen}{\binom{n}{k}}$ out of the Capital-Sigma Notation? 
2. Isn't $\color{red}{k}$ a Bound Variable, because $\color{red}{k}$ appears in the second combinatorial coefficient? I thought that you can't extract Bound Variables outside the summation?

Comment: Please don't hesitate to edit your answer to respond to my comment, rather than starting a separate comment.

Comment: @ugro The variables $n$ and $k$ are fixed. Only $m$ serves as index (hence is bound). Factor $\binom{n}{k}$ does not depend on $m$, so can be placed outside the summation sign.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I see that $\dbinom{n}{k}$ doesn't depend on $m$. But why are Bounds of Summation free variables? Why can $\dbinom{n}{k}$ be moved outside the summation, when $k$ is the upper bound of summation?

Comment: @ugro Do you agree that e.g. $\sum_{i=1}^kki=k\sum_{i=1}^ki$ where $k$ is an upper bound of summation?

Comment: @ugro The fact that $k$ serves as upper bound of a summation does not mean that $k$ can be labeled as a "bound variable". In the example in my former comment $k$ **is a bound** (noun) but also $k$ **is not a bound variable** (adjective). In the example $i$ is a bound variable.

Comment: Yes. I agree. $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\color{red}{k}i=\color{red}{k}(1 + \cdots + (k - 1) + k)=\color{red}{k}\sum\limits_{i=1}^ki$. But how does this answer my question? Our summation is more complicated, because we're dealing with  $\dbinom nk$, not $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\color{red}{k}i$.

Comment: @ugro You asserted that it was questionable whether $\binom{n}{k}$ could be removed from summation. This because $k$ was an upperbound of summation. In respond I gave you a more simple case to make more clear that this is not an objection. I am glad to hear you agree, and do not understand that you still see obstacles.

Comment: @ugro If by a summation of the form: $$\sum_{m=1}^nf(k,m,n)$$ we can write: $$f(k,m,n)=g(n,k)h(k,m,n)$$ then there is no objection to write it as:$$\sum_{m=1}^ng(n,k)h(k,m,n)=g(n,k)\sum_{m=1}^nh(k,m,n)$$Do you agree with that? It might be that e.g. $0\leq k\leq n$ is demanded but that does not spoil it.

Comment: Thanks so much for continuing to assist me with this! $\sum_{m=1}^ng(n,k)h(k,m,n)=g(n,k)\sum_{m=1}^nh(k,m,n)$ isn't obvious to me at all. Would a proof be the best way to understand this? Or can this be intuited?

Comment: @ugro Is it obvious to you that e.g.:$$\sum_{m=1}^4g(4,3)h(3,m,4)=g(4,3)\sum_{m=1}^4h(3,m,4)$$? Here $n$ and $k$ are replaced by fixed numbers. If you agree with it then you should also agree with the general case in which $n$ and $k$ are not yet substituted.

Comment: I see that you replaced $n, k$ with natural numbers. But no, alas, this isn't obvious to me.

Comment: @ugro Is it obvious to you that $$g(4,3)h(3,1,4)+g(4,3)h(3,2,4)+g(4,3)h(3,3,4)+g(4,3)h(3,4,4)$$ equals: $$g(4,3)(h(3,1,4)+h(3,2,4)+h(3,3,4)+h(3,4,4))$$?It says nothing more than that.

Comment: Thanks very much for your patience. Of course! Yes, that's obvious. But it's still not THAT obvious when you write $g(n,k)$! I don't know why, but my mind gets befuddled when I see $n$ as the upper bound and a free variable in $g(n,k)$.

Comment: @ugro Well, nothing goes wrong if you think of $n,k$ as fixed numbers that satisfy $0\leq k\leq n$. In my example they where fixed as $n=4$ and $k=3$. Good luck (last comment).

Answer (score 3):

Let us prove the general form of the identity given by @Richard.

$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty \binom ar \binom br \binom rc = \binom ac \binom{a+b-c}a.$$

Replacing $\binom ar \binom rc$ with:
$$
\binom ar \binom rc=\frac{a!}{r!(a-r)!}\frac{r!}{c!(r-c)!}
=\frac{a!}{c!(a-c)!}\frac{(a-c)!}{(a-r)!(r-c)!}=\binom ac\binom {a-c}{a-r},
$$
one obtains:
$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty \binom ar \binom br \binom rc =
\binom ac\sum_{r=0}^\infty \binom br \binom {a-c}{a-r}
=\binom ac \binom{a+b-c}a,
$$
where in the last equality the [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) was used.

Inserting $a=b=n$ and $c=n-k$ yields the identity of OP, as already was pointed out by @Richard.

Comment: Didn't know this identity was named after Vandermonde, and much simpler proof than mine. 1:0 for you, @user. +1